# Enviando um vector C++ para uma função Python

Tags: python, array, c++, vector

Eu tenho o seguinte função escrita em python em um arquivo .py:

```
def coordinate(arg):
    print arg

    return True
```

E um exemplo de código C++ em um arquivo .CPP

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

   bool result;
   std::vector<float> coords;

   Py_Initialize();

   ...

   result = ????
   Py_Finalize();

   return true;
}
```

Como enviar do código C++ o *float vector coords*, para a função Python coordinate()?

Comment: coords.data()? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Answer (score 2):

VC vai precisar compilar o código para criar um módulo python...

Crie um `setup.py` que utilize o `distutils` do python, esse arquivo será o responsável por criar/linkar um módulo escrito em C/C++ que mais tarde poderá ser importado dentro do seu Código Python.

`setup.py` básico de exemplo:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='NOMEMODULO', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('NOMEMODULO', ['codigo.cpp'])])
```

Agora você terá que compilar para criar seu módulo no python, vc terá que ter um compilador instalado e o módulo distutils devidamente instalado na sua versão python...

Na pasta que estão os seus arquivos C/C++ rode um:

```
python setup.py install
```

Antes de executar verifique se todos os `Paths` necessários estão nas variáveis ambientes do seu SO (onde está o exec do python, onde tá o exec do compilador, etc)

Se o comando acima rodar sem erros vc terá um módulo que poderá ser chamado dentro do seu código python..

```
import NOMEMODULO
```

Pronto agora você poderá chamar as funções que existem dentro do seu código C++ dentro do seu código Python...

Para trabalhar com vetores eu recomendo que você utilize o `Numpy`

Acabei de criar um exemplo simples (testevetor.c) para demonstrar como trabalhar com vetores do seu C/C++ e integrar com python com a ajuda do Numpy (estou usando python27, mas isso é a base para funcionar em qq versão):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
PyObject * testevetor()
{
          int vetor[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
          int tamanho = 5;
          PyObject * c = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1,&tamanho,PyArray_INT,vetor);
    
           return (PyObject*)c;
}



static PyObject *ErrorObject;

static PyMethodDef OiMethod[] = 
{
    {"testevetor", testevetor, METH_VARARGS, "teste do vetor"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC 
initoivetor(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("oivetor", OiMethod);
    import_array();
    ErrorObject = PyString_FromString("Oi.error");
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
        Py_FatalError("can't initialize module");
}
```

O Código acima apenas imprime os valores `0 1 2 3 4` como você pode notar eu estou usando o Numpy para criar um objeto que retorna esses valores, Só para demonstrar como se faz eu criei um módulo chamado `oivetor` e a função que retorna os valores se chama `testevetor()`

Bom feito isso é preciso criar um setup.py:

```
#build the modules

from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name='oivetor', version='1.0',  \
      ext_modules=[Extension('oivetor', ['testevetor.c'])])
```

Só colocar todos os arquivos em uma pasta em compilar (claro vc tem q ter um compilador e o distutils ai corretamente instalados e com path na variável ambiente ...

Só rodar um:

```
Python setup.py install (C:\Python27\testevetor>C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install)
```

Se nenhum erro acontecer vc deverá ter instalado o módulo...

```
C:\Python27\testevetor>C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'oivetor' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\
numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c testevetor.c -o bui
ld\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testevetor.o
testevetor.c:30:2: warning: no newline at end of file
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\oivetor.def
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testeve
tor.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\oivetor.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\
PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\oivetor.pyd
running install_lib
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\oivetor.pyd -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\oivetor-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\oivetor-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

Aqui nenhum erro: vamos testar ....

```
import oivetor
import numpy
print (numpy.array(oivetor.testevetor()))

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Funcionando perfeitamente, é quase que um tutorial isso huahuhua

Uso isso de monte para pegar vetores de áudios processando em C/C++ e passar para Python ....

Comment: Muito grato pela resposta, porém se não for pedir muito, poderia comentar o código ? Outra coisa, o que quis dizer com "Pronto agora você poderá chamar as funções que existem dentro do seu código C++ dentro do seu código Python..." e depois no final com "Uso isso de monte para pegar vetores de áudios processando em C/C++ e passar para Python ...." ?